# For loop in batch script not processing all records in input file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

The input.txt file contains 32 records, but only 18 records are processed in output.txt file using this for loop batch script. Any help greatly appreciated!

Code is below (please note that **echo >> %stdout%** has 50 lines in :process statement not copied here):

```
@echo off
set "source=C:\test\test\input.txt"
set "stdout=C:\test\test\output.txt"

for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims='" %%a in (%source%) do ( 
set partner=%%a&set blank=%%b&set comment=%%c&set host=%%d&set
call :process
)
goto :eof

:process
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET host_final=%host:~1%
echo >> %stdout%  partner=%partner% comment=%comment% host=%host_final%
echo >> %stdout%  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
....
echo >> %stdout%  (line 50 end of %partner%)
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof
```

Comment: If the problem is with the data file you should post the data file, otherwise we just can guess what is the problem... However, I could bet that the records that are not processed starts with a semicolon `;` that is the default `eol=;` character in `for /F` command.

Comment: Yes, right the problem was character ' |' in data file. I corrected the delimiter and the loop processed all records. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what all those lines are that you're echoing, but this is the basic structure I'd recommend:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "source=C:\test\test\input.txt"
Set "stdout=C:\test\test\output.txt"
For /F "UseBackQ EOL=' Tokens=1,3,4 Delims='" %%A In ("%source%"
) Do Call :Process "%%~A" "%%~B" "%%~C"
GoTo :EOF

:Process
Set "host=%~3"
>>"%stdout%" Echo partner=%~1 comment=%~2 host=%host:~1%
GoTo :EOF
```

*As I haven't seen the source file I have to assume that the tokens and delimiters you provided are correct.*

Comment: You beat me by a minute with exactly my answer. There are the `%` missing around stdout.

Comment: If I'd added them, I may not have beaten you! Now fixed.

Comment: Using this structure I got the same results in my output file. The problem was the delimiter. I corrected that and it loops and process all records. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, you didn't provide any information regarding the source file so we had to assume you had it correct, _(the most likely being a comma or a pipe)_. It shouldn't affect the correctness of my answer and I ask that you mark it as accepted accordingly.